# Rails: bootsnap. dlopen: no suitable image found. Did find: (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, dlopen

I am new to ruby-on-rails and mac. I am getting this error `dlopen(/Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/rubyeventmachine.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find: (LoadError)`. Caused by bootsnap.

I am trying to compile a ruby-on-rails project. using

`ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin18]`
`Rails 5.2.3`
`Bundler version 2.0.2`
`xcode-select version 2354`
`macOS Mojave version 10.14.6`

Which was running perfectly until now. I have searched and tried many things but not found a suitable solution.

Here is my traceback log:

```
2019-11-09 18:43:05 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome#driver_path= is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service#driver_path= instead.
Unable to load the EventMachine C extension; To use the pure-ruby reactor, require 'em/pure_ruby'
Traceback (most recent call last):
    95: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    94: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    93: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    92: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    91: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    90: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    89: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    88: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    87: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    86: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    85: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    84: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    83: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    82: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    81: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    80: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/test/test_command.rb:33:in `perform'
    79: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:39:in `run'
    78: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:50:in `load_tests'
    77: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:50:in `each'
    76: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:50:in `block in load_tests'
    75: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    74: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    73: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    72: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    71: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    70: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    69: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    68: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    67: from /Users/hasnainsomro/workspace/RTN2/test/models/cancel_reason_test.rb:12:in `<main>'
    66: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    65: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    64: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    63: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    62: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    61: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    60: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    59: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    58: from /Users/hasnainsomro/workspace/RTN2/test/test_helper.rb:2:in `<main>'
    57: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in `require_relative'
    56: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    55: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    54: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    53: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    52: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    51: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    50: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    49: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    48: from /Users/hasnainsomro/workspace/RTN2/config/environment.rb:2:in `<main>'
    47: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in `require_relative'
    46: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    45: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    44: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    43: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    42: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    41: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    40: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    39: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    38: from /Users/hasnainsomro/workspace/RTN2/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
    37: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    36: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
    35: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
    34: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
    33: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
    32: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    31: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    30: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    29: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    28: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    27: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    26: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/heroku-forward-0.4.0/lib/heroku-forward.rb:3:in `<main>'
    25: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    24: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    23: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    22: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    21: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    20: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    19: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    18: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    17: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/em-proxy-0.1.9/lib/em-proxy.rb:5:in `<main>'
    16: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    15: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    14: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    13: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    12: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    11: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    10: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     9: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
     8: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:8:in `<main>'
     7: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
     6: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
     5: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
     4: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
     3: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     2: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
     1: from /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require': dlopen(/Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/rubyeventmachine.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find: (LoadError)
    /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/rubyeventmachine.bundle: mach-o, but built for simulator (not macOS)
    /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/rubyeventmachine.bundle: mach-o, but built for simulator (not macOS) - /Users/hasnainsomro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/rubyeventmachine.bundle
```

Here is my gemlist:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) {|repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git"}

ruby '2.6.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'duktape'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.13'
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.13', :require => 'bcrypt'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
    gem 'annotate', '~> 2.7.5'
    gem 'pry', '~> 0.12.2'
    # gem 'annotate', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.2'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'jwt'
gem 'heroku-forward'

gem "active_model_serializers", require: true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have searched over google and found that I was using `eventmachine` gem without specifying platform. I had to install `eventmachine` gem with specifying platform.

> Although eventmachine is provided as x64-mingw platform gem, it doesn't support ruby-2.4 or 2.5 right now. Use `gem install eventmachine --platform ruby` in the meantime.

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/issues/96#issuecomment-361549776